# Crash when freeing up dynamic array of char

Tags: c++

When I try to free the char array for the name field of Student in dequeue() function, the program crashes.  The memory was previously allocated  in the createStudent() function.

I really can't see what I miss.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    int id;
    char* name;
};

struct QueueNode
{
    Student* info;
    QueueNode* next;
};

Student* createStudent(int id, char* name)
{
    Student* s = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    s->id = id;
    s->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(name) + 1);
    strcpy(s->name, name);

    return s;
}

QueueNode* createQueueNode(Student *s)
{
    QueueNode *queue = (QueueNode*)malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));
    queue->info = s;
    queue->next = nullptr;

    return queue;
}

void enqueueNode(QueueNode* &root, QueueNode* node)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        root = node;
    else
    {
        QueueNode* tmp = root;
        while (tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = node;
    }
}

Student* dequeueNode(QueueNode* &root)
{
    Student* s = nullptr;
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        QueueNode* tmp = root;
        s = tmp->info;
        root = root->next;
        free(tmp->info->name);    ----->>program crashes
        free(tmp->info);
        free(tmp);
    }
    return s;
}

void printqueue(QueueNode* root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        printf("Id:%d Name:%s\n", root->info->id, root->info->name);
        printqueue(root->next);
    }
}

void main()
{

    FILE* file = fopen("Text.txt", "r");
    int id; char buffer[50];
    QueueNode* queue = nullptr;

    fscanf(file, "%d", &id);
    while (!feof(file))
    {
        fgetc(file);
        fscanf(file, "%[^\n]s", buffer);
        Student* s = createStudent(id, buffer);
        QueueNode* node = createQueueNode(s);
        enqueueNode(queue, node);
        fscanf(file, "%d", &id);
    }
    dequeueNode(queue);
    printqueue(queue);
}
```

Comment: This is not C..

Comment: this is a very weird way to write C++ I must say, interpolating C and C++ when you could have simpler, one or the other

Comment: @Eugene,  this is `C++--`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `createStudent` this line:

```
s->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(name) + 1);
```

allocates the size of the *pointer* + 1, not the size of the string pointed by `name` (`sizeof` is misused here). So you're corrupting the memory list, and you see that when freeing it, because you triggered *undefined behaviour* before by copying a string too long for the allocated buffer (it may appear to work with short strings, though).

Fix:

```
s->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
```

or replace those 2 lines:

```
s->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(name) + 1);
strcpy(s->name, name);
```

by

```
s->name = strdup(name);
```

that handles the allocation & the copy properly.

Note: since it's C++ code you'd be better off with `std::string` to handle the strings. You'll save a lot of time hunting down crashes & memory leaks.

Comment: I didn't realized that I wrote sizeof instead of strlen, thank you very much